# Where to get BED files for regions that contain binding site motifs for specific transcription factors?

Tags: phylogenetics, bed, motifs, transcription-factors

Quick question, is there a place where one can download BED files for the binding motifs of certain transcription factors. In my case, I'm looking for a BED file for the genomic regions (enhancers) where TET2 binds to genome-wide. I'm looking to examine the DNA methylation levels in those regions.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

The standard answer would be to search [JASPAR](https://jaspar.genereg.net/search?q=tet2&collection=CORE&tax_group=vertebrates&tax_id=all&type=all&class=all&family=all&version=all), to get a curated dataset. However, there does not appear to be anything coming up for TET2 in the database.

If your TET2 gene is what you want specifically, you can find [papers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6442383/) that perform ChIP-seq and infer binding regions. I believe that [this Supp Table 3](https://genome.cshlp.org/content/suppl/2019/03/15/gr.239277.118.DC1/Supplemental_Table_S3.xlsx) contains information equivalent to a BED file for TET2.